# Route 'EnableNotification' should declare a screen

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am working on `react-native` and trying to integrate `react-navigation` https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/ for navigation. I am facing some difficulties while implementation.

### index.android.js

```
**
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  View,
  Text,
  Button,
  StyleSheet
} from "react-native";
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import EnableNotificationScreen from "./EnableNotification";

class SplashScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    console.disableYellowBox = true;
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={require("./img/talk_people.png")} />
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 22, textAlign: "center" }}>
          Never forget to stay in touch with the people that matter to you.
        </Text>
        <View style={{ width: 240, marginTop: 30 }}>
          <Button
            title="CONTINUE"
            color="#FE434C"
            onPress={() => navigate("EnableNotification")}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    padding: 16,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column"
  }
});

const ScheduledApp = StackNavigator(
  {
    Splash: { screen: SplashScreen },
    EnableNotification: { screen: EnableNotificationScreen }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Splash"
  }
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent("Scheduled", () => ScheduledApp);
```

### EnableNotification.js

```
/**
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

export class EnableNotification extends Component {
  render() {
    return <View><Text>Enable Notification</Text></View>;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `EnableNotification.js`, you export your `EnableNotification` class without default (which is a named export).

Then your import it with `import EnableNotificationScreen from "./EnableNotification"` in your `index.android.js`, which caused error.

You should

a) Export default your EnableNotification screen ie `export default class EnableNotification extends Component` or

b) Change to `import { EnableNotification } from "./EnableNotification"`

Read more on types of export [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are registering the `Scheduled` component. What you should do is register the `ScheduledApp` component.

Currently the `ScheduledApp` is not used, so it can't find the `EnableNotification` screen you are navigating to.

Register your app like this:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent("Scheduled", () => ScheduledApp);
```

What I also always do is define what the initial route is. You can do that by defining `initialRouteName` like so:

```
const ScheduledApp = StackNavigator({
  Splash: { screen: SplashScreen },
  EnableNotification: { screen: EnableNotification }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Splash'
});
```

Comment: I made changes as suggested, it did not work for me https://pastebin.com/dX0KjUH0